# Rotate image by a Button in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I have this code with which I load the image rotate.png and rotate clockwise. I would like to modify it by inserting two buttons, one for the start and one for the stop. If the stop button is not pressed, the wheel must start when the "start" button is pressed and slow down until it stops. Some idea?

```
import pygame, os
perc=os.getcwd()
percfile=perc+"\\ruota.png"


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def blitRotate(surf, image, pos, originPos, angle):

    # offset from pivot to center
    image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (pos[0] - originPos[0], pos[1]-originPos[1]))
    offset_center_to_pivot = pygame.math.Vector2(pos) - image_rect.center
    
    # roatated offset from pivot to center
    rotated_offset = offset_center_to_pivot.rotate(-angle)

    # roatetd image center
    rotated_image_center = (pos[0] - rotated_offset.x, pos[1] - rotated_offset.y)

    # get a rotated image
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rotated_image_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = rotated_image_center)

    # rotate and blit the image
    surf.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image_rect)
  
    # draw rectangle around the image
    # pygame.draw.rect(surf, (255, 0, 0), (*rotated_image_rect.topleft, *rotated_image.get_size()),2)

def blitRotate2(surf, image, topleft, angle):

    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(topleft = topleft).center)

    surf.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, (255, 0, 0), new_rect, 2)

try:
    
    image = pygame.image.load(percfile)
except:
    text = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 50).render('image', False, (255, 255, 0))
    image = pygame.Surface((text.get_width()+1, text.get_height()+1))
    #pygame.draw.rect(image, (0, 0, 255), (1, 1, *text.get_size()))
    image.blit(text, (1, 1))
w, h = image.get_size()

angle = 0
done = False
while not done:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    pos = (screen.get_width()/2, screen.get_height()/2)
    
    screen.fill(0)
    blitRotate(screen, image, pos, (w/2, h/2), angle)
    #blitRotate2(screen, image, pos, angle)
    angle += 1
    
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0]-20, pos[1]), (pos[0]+20, pos[1]), 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0], pos[1]-20), (pos[0], pos[1]+20), 3)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), pos, 7, 0)

    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you struggle? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. This code is just copied form here: https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/examples/surface_rotate/pygame_image_rotate_5_pivot_function.py or here https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateAroundPivot#main.py

Answer (score 0):

read this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-rotate-and-scale-images-using-pygame/

They explain better than I do.